Why C++ allocators use reinterpret_cast and how to avoid it?
I was trying to implement my own small allocator for testing purposes, and while designing it I thought that I don't know how to implement it without violating strict aliasing rule.
In most open-source from GitHub, C++ allocator method allocate<T> is an adapter to memory: it runs to the memory, asks for N consecutive std::bytes or unsigned chars, and then reinterpret_cast's this memory to T, and after that gives the memory back to its callee.
However, how does that not break the strict aliasing rule (even though the callee must call constructors itself, we cast std::byte* to T*). How is it possible to work-around it when implementing a simple buffer allocator that's suitable for most STL containers?

Implementation(s) doesn't have to follow c++ rules!

Related/dupe: Implementing a std::vector like container without undefined behavior

Strict aliasing is not about reinterpreting pointers, but about dereferencing them. Simply returning a pointer to raw memory doesn't break strict aliasing.

C programmers often say that it is not possible to write an equivalent of malloc in conformant C. For the very same reason: at a moment you must find some memory and decide that 1/ it initially has no type and 2/ you can bless it into one type. But for safety reasons user level programs are not allowed to do that.

This is fine because after allocate, you construct which places an object in the memory that was allocated

Another related/dupe: How does malloc work with strict aliasing - can it only be violated within a single compilation unit? that asks basically the same question saying "how a memory allocator can work without violating the strict aliasing rules" Also C memory allocator and strict aliasing

An implementation is free to associate some form of undefined behaviour with some reliable outcome, and then exploit the fact it has done that.    So, no workaround needed.    In other words, a compiler and (internals of) an implementation of the standard library are free to use constructs with undefined behaviour, as long as they produce required behaviours (e.g. in this case, that std::allocate<T> behaves as required for a programmer using the compiler and standard library).

Strict aliasing is violated when you pretend that there's an object at a certain memory location, but in reality there isn't. (You do that by reinterpret_casting a pointer/reference and then dereferencing it, where only the deferencing itself is UB.)
It doesn't stop you from using placement-new to change what type of object is stored in some memory, and then accessing it.
For example:
#include <string>

int main()
{
    alignas(std::string) char buf[sizeof(std::string)];

    *reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(buf) = "foo"; // UB

    std::string *ptr = new(buf) std::string;
    *ptr = "foo"; // Legal.
}


Seems to me that a mention of std::launder might also be relevant here.

@JesperJuhl Shrug. It's somewhat related, but you can use allocators without it.

std::allocator<T>::allocate does not construct any objects of type T1, std::construct_at does. It's ok to reinterpret_cast a void * to a T *, if you then go on to start the lifetime of a T in the memory pointed to.

allocate does start the lifetime of an array of T, but not the T subobjects of that array.

